# Find element and render on passing codition

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary, filter

I find names for some objects and have following source code:

```
const findAndRenderName = (projectId: number| undefined) => {

  //i want to render here something when the condtion will pass
  projectList?.map(project => projectId = project.id)

}

return (
  <DetailsBox title={t('catalogPage.componentDetails.specs.used')}>

  {
    component?.projects.map(project => findAndRenderName(project.id))
  }

  </DetailsBox>
);
```

How to make kind of `if` from the `map` function, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is

```
projectList?.map(project => {
   if(projectId === project.id){
     // do something
   }
})
```

of if you refer to the second `map`

```
component?.projects.map(project => {  
  if(findAndRenderName(project.id)){
    // do something
  }
})
```